# button tag inside anchor tag not working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a problem.
I'm using a button in an a tag and I want the button clickable area to be the same as its container a. How can I do it?

Here an example of my code:

```
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;LOGIN
    <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" runat="server" onserverclick="btnLogin_ServerClick">
    </button>
    </a>
```

EDIT:
Tried the height and width 100%, here's what happens:
[Small rect. is the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr2oi.png)

Comment: Insert button inside tag a isn't valid HTML5

Comment: I need it like this

Comment: you need iy like this but it's wrong, you need to correct it

Comment: Search for ```css button maker``` there are tools that can make the button for you and also ```w3c validator``` to know if your html code is correct

Comment: Ok, I will. But for now I need to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your approach by moving the content `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;LOGIN` to be inside button tag.

Note : you can't using button element inside anchor element, it isn't valid HTML5 according to the [HTML5 Spec Document from W3C](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="aan btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
    <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" runat="server" onserverclick="btnLogin_ServerClick"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; LOGIN</button>
  </a>
```

Comment: Use "<i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;LOGIN" text with button.

Comment: Almost there. Now only the icon and the text LOGIN are pressable. All the <a> box around is not!

Comment: Do you need full width <a>?

Comment: Yes! All of it!

Comment: set the button width: 100%.